# Convert python pandas series to a dataframe and split the column into two

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my series named table

```
Host
cds170.yyz.llnw.net     1
cds172.yyz.llnw.net     3
cds180.yyz.llnw.net     1
cds182.yyz.llnw.net     1
cds183.yyz.llnw.net     3
fcds113.yyz.llnw.net    1
Name: Host, dtype: int64
```

This is the dataframe that I want

```
Host                  count
cds170.yyz.llnw.net     1
cds172.yyz.llnw.net     3
cds180.yyz.llnw.net     1
cds182.yyz.llnw.net     1
cds183.yyz.llnw.net     3
fcds113.yyz.llnw.net    1
```

I have tried

```
table = pd.DataFrame(table)
table = pd.DataFrame(table.Host.str.split().tolist(), columns = ['Host', 'count'])
```

But I get

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 1), indices imply (2, 1)
```

Can someone please help me do this?

Comment: By the way don't use the code snippet tools for python code, as you can't run it using the widgets, it's better to select the code using the cursor and then pressing ctrl+k, also you can upvote too ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
In [5]:

pd.DataFrame({'Host':s.index, 'Count':s.values})
Out[5]:
   Count                  Host
0      1   cds170.yyz.llnw.net
1      3   cds172.yyz.llnw.net
2      1   cds180.yyz.llnw.net
3      1   cds182.yyz.llnw.net
4      3   cds183.yyz.llnw.net
5      1  fcds113.yyz.llnw.net
```

So you can construct a dict inline and pass this as the data to a DataFrame ctor